# How do you return the leaderboard position on game center

Tags: ios, objective-c, game-center

I have a game where on IOS where I want to show the users stance compared to the rest of the players. I can make my own database and input the scores and users that way, but it would be so much easier to use game centers database. Is there some simple function I can use for this?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes is possible:

```
- (IBAction)GameCenter:(id)sender {
    GKGameCenterViewController *gameCenterController = [[GKGameCenterViewController alloc] init];
    if (gameCenterController != nil){
        gameCenterController.gameCenterDelegate = self;
        [self presentViewController: gameCenterController animated: YES completion:nil];
    }
}

- (void)gameCenterViewControllerDidFinish:(GKGameCenterViewController *)gameCenterViewController
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

I suggest to you read this:

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-sdk-game-center-achievements-and-leaderboards-part-1--mobile-5701

Hope this help ;)